# translations are not visible for the community tabs even after placing the translations in import file

Tags: community, translation, translation-workbench

I am trying to import the translated content to my community.
Everything else is getting translated except the tabs.
Tabs are not present in the navigation menu.

Comment: If you wish to make an edit to your question or reply to the answer below, please log in to your account.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Known Issue: Translations are not reflected in community immediately after publishing it](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eim3QAA), it looks like the only thing you can do is to wait 24 hours until translations are published:

> **Workaround**
>
> No workarounds at this time. The translation should be
>   updated in the community 24 hours after you've updated the translation
>   and published your community.